# Necessary data size to evaluate Hadoop performance

Tags: docker, hadoop, bigdata

I'm running Hadoop with 3 datanodes on a single machine using Docker containers. I've run a KMeans algorithm on a small simulated dataset with 200 data points.

Because of the Hadoop overhead, the process takes a long time, about 2 or 3 minutes, while running kmeans locally in R takes few seconds.

I wonder how big my dataset has to be to Hadoop overperform the non-distributed approach, and if that's possible since I'm running all the nodes on single machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the number of cores and RAM available to process the data, that matters more than the amount of data itself, so limiting Hadoop jobs inside containers is actually running little JVM containers within those containers. Therefore, it's expected that giving one full machine access to process the same amount of data will be much more likely to process quicker, and I'm sure there's a way to write the same distributed algorithm without Hadoop

Besides that, if the data itself isn't splittable or less than the hdfs block size, then it'll only be able to be processed by a single mapreduce task anyway. You didn't mention the size, but I suspect 200 data points is only a few MB at most

Comment: So even if I have one Docker container per machine, would it still have limit access to RAM and cores? I'm asking this because I'd like to take advantage of Docker portability instead of having to install Hadoop in every node in the cluster

Comment: Yes, by definition of a container, it has limited access to system resources. Hadoop wasn't designed to run within Docker, anyway